# Populate list based on criterias on other lists in Excel

Tags: excel

In this problem I will provide you with the situation, and a picture for name reference and visualization of the problem.

I have list called **ID** in column C. The list is populated, but some rows are blank.
I also have two lists in column E and F, called **List1** and **List2**.

I want to create **List3**:
**List3** shall copy the values from **list1**, but copy the values from **list2** for the rows where list2 is populated (list2 dominates list1).
At the same time - copying shall only take place for the rows where **ID**-column is populated. This means that **List3** shall blank for the same rows where **ID**-column blanks.

Do anyone have a solution to my problem?
In advance, thank you!

(PS: If there's a way to make list3 dynamic with the total length of ID-column, that would also be great, but not necessary.)

[image: Picture provided here.]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns given, you can use this formula:

`= IF(C2<>"",IF(F2<>"",F2,E2),"")`

It first checks if there are data in colum C, if yes, it checks colum F: if there is a value, takes it, otherwise takes the one from E.

If there is no value in C, it returns nothing

To spill the values down you can use:

```
=BYROW(C12:F16,LAMBDA(d,
                LET(ID,INDEX(d,1,1),
                    List1,INDEX(d,1,3),
                    List2,INDEX(d,1,4),
                    IF(ID<>"",IF(List2<>"",List2,List1),""))))
```